# Angular6 - SpringBoot Basic auth

Tags: typescript, angular6

I have installed `nvm 1.1.7` and `Node.js` version 8.11.1.

Now I have installed `angular@cli` version 6.1.3 and I create an Angular project with `ng new`.

I'm trying to do a `Basic Authentication` with `SpringBoot` as server. I have followed a tons of guides but I cannot set authentication params inside `HttpHeader`.

If I wrote:

```
var headers_object = new HttpHeaders();
headers_object.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
headers_object.set('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa('guest:guest1234'));
```

And then:

```
console.log(headers_object.get('Content-Type'));
```

it prints `null`.. If I wrote:

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
};
console.log(httpOptions.headers.get('Content-Type'));
```

It prints `application/json`. If I check the `HttpHeaders` code, I can see clearly the `set` method.

In my `package.json` I see:

```
"@angular/animations": "^6.1.0",
"@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
"@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
"@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
"@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
"@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
"core-js": "^2.5.4",
"rxjs": "6.0.0",
"zone.js": "~0.8.26"
```

Whats wrong??

-------------------------- UPDATE -----------------------

I manage to send the (I think..) headers param as follows:

```
let httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders()
          .set('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa('guest:guest1234'))
          .set('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 

console.log(httpHeaders.get('Content-Type')); // print correct
const httpOptions = {
  headers: httpHeaders
};
console.log(httpOptions.headers.get('Content-Type')); // print correct

return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/hello', httpOptions); // return 401!!
```

I'm really going mad for this stupid thing... PS: Cors are disabled by Chrome extension.. and with Postman I reach the server...

Answer (score 0):

Solved.. problem was server side.. I forget:

```
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
```

Inside `Spring Security Configuration` class. Anyway with Postman I could still reach the server even without the code above.. I still have doubts about it:

```
var headers_object = new HttpHeaders();
headers_object.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
headers_object.set('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa('guest:guest1234'));
console.log(headers_object.get('Content-Type')); // printing null
```

I'm absolutely new to Angular and I will search a `Typescript 2.9` documentation for it.

Any help (or documentation hint) is highly appreciate!